# Azure alert monitor condition always stay the same

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-logic-apps, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I have implemented alerting on my infrastructure. The problem is that the monitor condidition never changes to resolve. Anyone with the same problem?

Kind regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Different types of alerts resolve differently. E.g. log alerts do not resolve automatically - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-unified-log#log-search-alert-rule---firing-and-state

Comment: they reallyt should add that feature

Answer (score 1):

Summarize from the comments for others' reference:

As stackoverflowusrone mentioned, different types of alerts resolve differently and also provide a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-unified-log#log-search-alert-rule---firing-and-state).

Here I provide some more information about it, we can know the alert's logic by this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-overview#monitoring-at-scale-using-metric-alerts-in-azure-monitor)
[image]

By the way, if you want azure develop team add some feature, you can raise a feedback ticket on this [page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/913690-azure-monitor).